# Implementing `Auto` property in component's persistent

Tags: delphi, properties, components, delphi-7, persistent

I have a component which has a corresponding persistent. This persistent is of course published as a property of the component, showing in the object inspector. It has a few different properties of its own, mainly 4 integers (Left, Top, Right, Bottom). I also have a property in this persistent called `Auto` which is intended to automatically calculate the 4 integers based on the size of the component.

More specifically, this graphic component has a border around it, each edge can have a different sized border. This persistent and its properties specify the thickness of the border on each side. When `Auto` is enabled, the 4 border edges are calculated based on the size of the component.

Now it seems to work fine for the most part, except, somehow this `Auto` property keeps going back to False randomly. Also, in design-time, when resizing the component with `Auto` enabled, it does in fact calculate things accordingly, perfectly. But, in run-time, it goes back to False, and no longer calculates them anymore. Upon saving with `Auto` enabled, closing the form, then re-opening it, this `Auto` property is back to False again.

The 4 integer properties have setters, which if they are set, it turns this `Auto` property to false. I'm assuming this is what's causing it to keep going to false again, except, I'm not telling it to set these properties anywhere.

Here's the persistent:

```
  TJDGlassBorder = class(TPersistent)
  private
    fOwner: TJDGlass; //This is the parent component
    fGlow: Integer;
    fBottom: Integer;
    fLeft: Integer;
    fTop: Integer;
    fRight: Integer;
    fColor: TColor;
    fOnEvent: TNotifyEvent;
    fAuto: Bool;
    procedure SetBottom(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetGlow(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetRight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetTop(const Value: Integer);
    function GetBottom: Integer;
    function GetLeft: Integer;
    function GetRight: Integer;
    function GetTop: Integer;
    procedure SetAuto(const Value: Bool);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TJDGlass);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Event;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Auto: Bool read fAuto write SetAuto default True;
    property Left: Integer read GetLeft write SetLeft default 3;
    property Top: Integer read GetTop write SetTop default 2;
    property Right: Integer read GetRight write SetRight default 3;
    property Bottom: Integer read GetBottom write SetBottom default 4;
    property Color: TColor read fColor write SetColor;
    property Glow: Integer read fGlow write SetGlow default 1;
    property OnEvent: TNotifyEvent read fOnEvent write fOnEvent;
  end;

/////////////

{ TJDGlassBorder }

procedure TJDGlassBorder.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited Assign(Source);
  Event;
end;

constructor TJDGlassBorder.Create(AOwner: TJDGlass);
begin
  fOwner:= AOwner;
  fAuto:= True;
  fColor:= clBlack;
  fGlow:= 1;
  Event;
end;

destructor TJDGlassBorder.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.Event;
begin
  if assigned(fOwner) then 
    if fOwner <> nil then
      fOwner.Invalidate;
  if assigned(fOnEvent) then
    fOnEvent(Self);
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetBottom: Integer;
begin
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= Max(2, fOwner.Height div 10);
        fBottom:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Result:= fBottom;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetLeft: Integer;
begin
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= (Top + Bottom) div 2;
        fLeft:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Result:= fLeft;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetRight: Integer;
begin
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= (Top + Bottom) div 2;
        fRight:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Result:= fRight;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetTop: Integer;
begin
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= Max(1, fOwner.Height div 30);
        fTop:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Result:= fTop;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetAuto(const Value: Bool);
begin
  fAuto := Value;
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetBottom(const Value: Integer);
begin          
  fAuto:= False;
  fBottom := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  fColor := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetGlow(const Value: Integer);
begin
  fGlow := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
begin         
  fAuto:= False;
  fLeft := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetRight(const Value: Integer);
begin       
  fAuto:= False;
  fRight := Value; 
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetTop(const Value: Integer);
begin           
  fAuto:= False;
  fTop := Value;
  Event;
end;
```

---

**EDIT:**

I attempted 3 more things in the above code, and still have the problem. This is what I did:

1: Published the `Auto` property after the other 4 properties, thinking of the order that these properties are retrieved.

```
published
  property Auto: Bool read fAuto write SetAuto default True;
  property Left: Integer read GetLeft write SetLeft default 3;
  property Top: Integer read GetTop write SetTop default 2;
  property Right: Integer read GetRight write SetRight default 3;
  property Bottom: Integer read GetBottom write SetBottom default 4;
```

Changed to:

```
published
  property Left: Integer read GetLeft write SetLeft default 3;
  property Top: Integer read GetTop write SetTop default 2;
  property Right: Integer read GetRight write SetRight default 3;
  property Bottom: Integer read GetBottom write SetBottom default 4;
  property Auto: Bool read fAuto write SetAuto default True;
```

2: In the property setters for these integers, I'm checking to see if the new value differs from the existing value...

```
procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetTop(const Value: Integer);
begin         
  if Value <> fTop then begin  
    fAuto:= False;
    fTop := Value;
    Event;
  end;
end;
```

3: In the property getters for these integers, I changed how it checks the existing value...

```
function TJDGlassBorder.GetTop: Integer;
begin
  Result:= fTop;
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= Max(1, fOwner.Height div 30);
        fTop:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Again, none of these attempts worked, I still have this problem.

Comment: Read the comment I made to the answer you posted. Also, you've learned already that `default` prevents the property from being stored unless the value is different than the default, but it doesn't SET the property to default. Why would you think treatment of integer properties would behave differently than Booleans?

Comment: @KenWhite: I never mentioned any difference in the treatment. But I do know it matters in what order the properties are published. When saving to the DFM, I belive it saves them in the order that they're published in the class, at the same time, they are then loaded in the order that they're saved in the DFM. If `Auto` is loaded first, then the 4 integers, then the integer setting will trigger the `Auto` to be switched back to false again, even if it was saved as `True`. Moving `Auto` to be published after the integers makes it load from the DFM after the integers, which was part of the reason

Comment: Order makes no difference. They're loaded according to RTTI (which is why all properties stored in the DFM must be `published`, and will automatically add the `{$M+}` compiler option. Your logic is based on a misunderstanding of how streaming works. It's possible you have setter procedures that are screwing things up, but it's not possible for the streaming mechanism to be doing so.

Comment: I've seen many places in the standard VCL library (don't know specific examples) where it's explicitly commented in the code that certain properties have to be published before/after certain other properties for certain reasons. I'm not entirely sure what order things are saved/loaded, but I'm sure that the order of loading/setting the properties from the DFM do make a big difference. Imaging 1) set `Auto` to True, 2) Set `Left` to 20, then 3) setting `Left` to 20 (with my code above) will set `Auto` back to false.

Comment: (that is, even without thinking about the DFM, think generally setting these properties in different orders)

Comment: It's changing them because your setters are doing so, the same reason there are comments in the VCL that mention that (I haven't seen them, but I'll take your word). You could prevent that by checking the `ComponentState` flags and taking action according to the value to avoid calling the setters at an inopportune time.

Comment: Well, as my answer below indicates, I have already fixed this problem long before you even commented on it. I was merely explaining what I did to fix it, and why the changes were what I needed to do. Whether it's runtime/designtime isn't any issue of mine - other than that happened to be how I found the problem in the first place. Thanks for all your input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIXED!**

The 3 attempts I put in my edit above were partially the problem, but the actual fix was removing the `default` of the `Auto` property. The thing is, I had this defaulted to True, which, in this case, that property is not saved in the DFM file. Therefore it did not even attempt to set this `Auto` property. Removing the Default fixed, because now whether it's true or false, it's always saved in the DFM file, therefore always setting this value. The order of publishing the properties was also half of the problem.

---

Here's the final code for what I posted above:

```
  TJDGlassBorder = class(TPersistent)
  private
    fOwner: TJDGlass; //This is the parent component
    fGlow: Integer;
    fBottom: Integer;
    fLeft: Integer;
    fTop: Integer;
    fRight: Integer;
    fColor: TColor;
    fOnEvent: TNotifyEvent;
    fAuto: Bool;
    procedure SetBottom(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetGlow(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetRight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetTop(const Value: Integer);
    function GetBottom: Integer;
    function GetLeft: Integer;
    function GetRight: Integer;
    function GetTop: Integer;
    procedure SetAuto(const Value: Bool);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TJDGlass);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Event;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Left: Integer read GetLeft write SetLeft default 3;
    property Top: Integer read GetTop write SetTop default 2;
    property Right: Integer read GetRight write SetRight default 3;
    property Bottom: Integer read GetBottom write SetBottom default 4;
    property Color: TColor read fColor write SetColor;
    property Glow: Integer read fGlow write SetGlow default 1;
    property OnEvent: TNotifyEvent read fOnEvent write fOnEvent;
    property Auto: Bool read fAuto write SetAuto;
  end;

/////////////

{ TJDGlassBorder }

procedure TJDGlassBorder.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited Assign(Source);
  Event;
end;

constructor TJDGlassBorder.Create(AOwner: TJDGlass);
begin
  fOwner:= AOwner;
  fAuto:= True;
  fColor:= clBlack;
  fGlow:= 1;
  Event;
end;

destructor TJDGlassBorder.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.Event;
begin
  if assigned(fOwner) then 
    if fOwner <> nil then
      fOwner.Invalidate;
  if assigned(fOnEvent) then
    fOnEvent(Self);
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetBottom: Integer;
begin
  Result:= fBottom;
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= Max(2, fOwner.Height div 10);
        fBottom:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetLeft: Integer;
begin
  Result:= fLeft;
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= (Top + Bottom) div 2;
        fLeft:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetRight: Integer;
begin
  Result:= fRight;
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= (Top + Bottom) div 2;
        fRight:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TJDGlassBorder.GetTop: Integer;
begin
  Result:= fTop;
  if fAuto then begin
    if assigned(fOwner) then begin
      if fOwner <> nil then begin
        Result:= Max(1, fOwner.Height div 30);
        fTop:= Result;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetAuto(const Value: Bool);
begin
  fAuto := Value;
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetBottom(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> fBottom then begin
    fAuto:= False;
    fBottom := Value;  
    Event;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  fColor := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetGlow(const Value: Integer);
begin
  fGlow := Value;  
  Event;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetLeft(const Value: Integer);
begin         
  if Value <> fLeft then begin
    fAuto:= False;
    fLeft := Value;  
    Event;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetRight(const Value: Integer);
begin       
  if Value <> fRight then begin
    fAuto:= False;
    fRight := Value; 
    Event;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetTop(const Value: Integer);
begin        
  if Value <> fTop then begin   
    fAuto:= False;
    fTop := Value;
    Event;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you want it to basically be True unless specifically set otherwise, set it to True in the constructor. Then when the .DFM is streamed in, any stored value in it will replace the one you set in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

First, as you've already noted, remove the `default`. If you want the property to be `True` unless specifically set to another value, set it in the constructor. When the `DFM` is streamed in from your executable, any value stored in it will replace the one set in the constructor.

Second, your issue is based in part on faulty logic. :) If you want the `Auto` property to control the others (meaning if `Auto = True` then ignore any values set for the other properties), then test for that in the setters:

```
procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetTop(const Value: Integer);
begin
  // Only change the value if Auto is not True         
  if (not FAuto) and (Value <> fTop) then 
  begin  
    fTop := Value;
    Event;
  end;
end;

procedure TJDGlassBorder.SetAuto(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if (Value <> FAuto) then
  begin
    FAuto := Value;
    if FAuto then
    begin
      FTop := 0;     // Or whatever. Set field and not property to 
      FLeft := 0;    // avoid the setter's side effects
      FWidth := 0;
      FHeight := 0;
    end;
    // Whatever you need to do now.
  end;
end;
```

Doing it this way means that you avoid the automatic changes by calling the setter.

I'd suggest if you can, you defer the call to `Event` at runtime by using `Loaded`; this is called after the component is fully streamed from the .dfm, and you can perform any calculations or redraws there after all properties are set. You can determine if you're in the IDE or at runtime by examining the `ComponentState` property; if it contains `csDesigning`, you're in the IDE at designtime, and if `csLoading` is set you're in runtime. (`ComponentState` is a set, so you check using `if csDesigning in ComponentState`.)

Comment: Actually, it is supposed to change fAuto upon setting the value, both in designtime and runtime. That is the whole purpose of it. Same way that setting, for example, 'ParentColor' of some other VCL control works. It just wasn't working as expected in the first place, but I have figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, if the user (either in design or run time) decides to assign one of the 4 integer values, then it is supposed to turn the Auto property to false.

Comment: Also, I don't have FTop, FLeft etc. if auto is enabled - it needs to dynamically calculate this in the property getter based on the current size of the control. If I use these fields like this, then when the control is resized, it will stay the same. The whole point of this is to calculate these values on the spot, and not to store the fields.

Comment: If Auto is *not* enabled, where do you get the values (if you don't have internal storage for them)? For instance, let's say I set the four values (`Top`, `Left`, `Width`, and `Height`), and then *accidentally* set `Auto` to `True`, realize the mistake, and set it back to `False`. Do I have to then go back and reset the other four properties? If not, you have to have storage for them somewhere internally. Right? Oh, yeah - you **do** have `fLeft`, `fTop`, etc. - I just looked. :)

Comment: Yes, I do have them, but I don't use them if Auto is enabled. The property getters check the Auto property, if Auto is enabled, then it looks at the parent control's dimensions and calculates the values on the spot. And if you accidently enabled 'ParentColor' in for example a Panel, and switch it back to False, same deal.

Comment: I just edited my answer and added the final working code so you can see how I have it working.